# How to Use AJax to read page being displayed in the address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok so I am wrapping up my website now. I am using an AJAX/ JQUERY code to load the pages inside of a div in the initial index page of my website. but I want people to be able to share these things using jquery social share buttons plugin that I purchased but how would they be able to share individual pages like mydomain.com/artist/myartist if the address bar only reads mydomain.com?

Or lets say I pass on a link to a specific section of my site that I want ppl to visit once they click the link. For example

www.mydomain.com/store to load the store page instead of the initial landing page of my website where they would have to navigate to my store page instead of being able to click on the link in the navigation system

I dont know if I am asking the question correctly but check out my website to see what i am talking about http://www.Trillumonopoly.com

Below is the jquery/ajax code that I am using to navigate my website

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
method: 'GET',
url: "pages/promo.html",
success: function(content)
{
    $('#contentarea').html (content);
}
});
});



$('.menu_nav') .click (function () {
var href = $(this) .attr('href');
$('#contentarea').hide() .load(href).fadeIn('normal');

return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you don't have individual pages to link to. You need to first that before you can do anything else.

First make the site work without Ajax (create separate, complete pages, with unique URLs, for each page).

Then, when the link / form / whatever to load `/example.page` is activated, go through these steps:

1. Fetch the content needed to convert the current page into the page the server would give you if you asked for `/example.page`
2. Update the DOM with that content
3. Use [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to update the URL in the address bar

Also make sure you have a [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_popstate_event) handler registered so that the Back and Forward buttons built into the browser continue to work.

Comment: Everything in my navigation has its own html page with meta keywords etc. Just wont display properly without being displayed in the initial index page of my website. but Everything on there is seperated into its own page.

Comment: @TrillumonopolyInc — You miss my point. You need to change things so that they can be displayed independently.